# How to get the absolute url of <img /> in PHP?

Tags: php, html

The `src` of the `<img>` is known,as well as the url of the target webpage,like `http://test.com/directory/hi.html`，how to implement the general function to retrieve the absolute url of the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would:

1. Check if the img URL started with a host value, and if so, return it, as it's already absolute

   - Parse the web page URL to get the base host value
   - Check if the img src is relative to the root or the directory, and append to the base host value as appropriate.

[parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) is going to be the function of choice here.  I was feeling brave, so I implemented it for you:

```
function getAbsoluteImageUrl($pageUrl,$imgSrc)
{
    $imgInfo = parse_url($imgSrc);
    if (! empty($imgInfo['host'])) {
        //img src is already an absolute URL
        return $imgSrc;
    }
    else {
        $urlInfo = parse_url($pageUrl);
        $base = $urlInfo['scheme'].'//'.$urlInfo['host'];
        if (substr($imgSrc,0,1) == '/') {
            //img src is relative from the root URL
            return $base . $imgSrc;
        }
        else {
            //img src is relative from the current directory
               return 
                    $base
                    . substr($urlInfo['path'],0,strrpos($urlInfo['path'],'/'))
                    . '/' . $imgSrc;
        }
    }
}

//tests

$host = 'http://test.com/directory/hi.html';
$imgSrc = '/images/lolcat.jpg';
echo getAbsoluteImageUrl($host,$imgSrc);
//echos  http//test.com/images/lolcat.jpg 

$host = 'http://test.com/directory/hi.html';
$imgSrc = 'images/lolcat.jpg';
echo getAbsoluteImageUrl($host,$imgSrc);
//echos  http//test.com/directory/images/lolcat.jpg

$host = 'http://test.com/directory/hi.html';
$imgSrc = 'http://images.com/lolcat.jpg';
echo getAbsoluteImageUrl($host,$imgSrc);
//echos  http://images.com/lolcat.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url), you can do something like this:

1. Parse the page url into its parts (scheme, domain, path, file, query, fragment)
2. Rebuild the url for the img url, depending on how the img url is.

   - Img url begins with '/', it's an absolute url, so we build the img url like `"$scheme://$domain$img_url"`
   - Img url doesn't begin with '/', so it's relative, so we build the img url like `"$scheme://$domain/$path/$img_url"`. This also works if img_url is ".././"-style, because those will be parsed by the server.

You may also want to exclude img urls that start with a scheme or domain ('xx://' or 'xx.xx/').

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't take into account a src that starts with //. This leaves the scheme open ended depending on the origin. I think there's also a missing colon in their answer. Here's my slightly modified version that seems to work fine. Note it uses PHP7 syntax.

```
function getAbsoluteImageUrl($pageUrl,$imgSrc)
{
    $imgInfo = parse_url($imgSrc);
    var_dump(parse_url($imgSrc));

    if (!empty($imgInfo['host'])) {
        //img src is already an absolute URL
        if (substr($imgSrc,0,2) == '//') {
            return (parse_url($pageUrl)['scheme'] ?? "http") . ":" . $imgSrc;
        } else {
            return $imgSrc;
        }
    }
    else {
        $urlInfo = parse_url($pageUrl);
        $base = $urlInfo['scheme'].'://'.$urlInfo['host'];
        if (substr($imgSrc,0,1) == '/') {
            //img src is relative from the root URL
            return $base . $imgSrc;
        }
        else {
            //img src is relative from the current directory
               return
                    $base
                    . substr($urlInfo['path'],0,strrpos($urlInfo['path'],'/'))
                    . '/' . $imgSrc;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question well you can define the APPLICATION_PATH in the application root as below and use it afterwards:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
...
<img src="<?php APPLICATION_PATH ?>/path/to/image.png" alt="" />
...
```

Comment: That's assuming it's a local image. I think the OP wants a URL.

Comment: need more clarifications, absolute url?! do you mean base url?! an example may help!

Comment: The OP has the URL of the HTML file, and the **relative** URL of the image to that HTML file. He needs to turn this into an **absolute** URL of the image.